# How do I post images to reddit in iOS / Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, http-headers

I am trying to post an image to reddit; however, I only kind of know what I am doing.  I am using objective c for my iphone app.

Prior to the code listed below I obtain a modhash and cookie by logging in prior to the upload and use NSLog to determine that I truly am receiving them.  Then I use a JSON Parser to separate them into separate variables.

I was not sure what all of the POST argument values were supposed to be so I kind of guessed.  The necessary arguments are uh, file, formid, header, ing_type, name, and sponsor.

The documentation for reddit api is http://www.reddit.com/dev/api  I believe that I want to use the POST /api/upload_sr_img method...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.reddit.com/api/upload_sr_img"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *httpBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?uh=%@&file=%@&formid=''header=%@&img_type=%@&name=%@&sponsor=%@",modhash,UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.memeImage.image),@"test",@"png",@"Drew",@"Drew'sApp"];

[request setHTTPBody:[httpBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
NSError *imgError = NULL;
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&imgError];

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSDictionary *responseJson = [json valueForKey:@"json"];


NSLog(@"response is: %@",response);
NSLog(@"imgError is: %@",imgError);
NSLog(@"result is: %@",result);
NSLog(@"json is: %@",json);
NSLog(@"responseJson is: %@",responseJson);
```

Could use any help I can get.

Also, I was not sure if I needed to send a content-type or even what it would be.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The Apple dev documentation has extensive, detailed examples of how to do this.  Have you read through those?

Comment: Well the issue is more trying to understand Reddit's documentation... I don't know what should be in formed, header, name, or sponsor.  I also don't know if I am required to send a content-type and other main http header information.  If I should send them what should I send in their place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this library: https://github.com/MattFoley/MFRedditPostController

- You can use the provided UI or create your own.